# Can't CAST TEXT field successfully into a DECIMAL (18,2) data type

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio

Client is looking to send a coupon for any orders over $250.  However, they are passing the order value as a `TEXT` field, not a `DECIMAL`.  I'm trying to run the query by using `CAST`, but no luck.  I've searched posts here, but to no avail.

Sample of what we've tried:  `CAST(ordervalue as decimal(18,2)) > 249.99`

where `ordervalue` is currently a `TEXT` field, but obviously we can't do `greater than` on `TEXT`.

Can someone shed some light on this one?

Comment: Have you tried using CONVERT()? e.g. `CONVERT(decimal, ordervalue)`. I only bring it up because SFMC is wonky in what works in some areas may not work in others and vice versa.

Comment: When I do try CONVERT the system asks me to declare a name for the variable, so it becomes `CONVERT(decimal, ordervalue) as ordervalue` and it still doesn't work

Comment: shooting from the hip, why not do your select with cast in a sub query so that the main query will only see it as a decimal.  Something like `SELECT a.pkey, a.ordervalue FROM ( SELECT pkey, CAST(ordervalue as decimal(18,2)) as ordervalue FROM yourDE) a WHERE a.ordervalue > 249.99`

Comment: no dice, @gortonington... I will keep trying, but I may have to resort to brute force and export/re-import then query.

Comment: Plot twist - I was going through a brute-force build, and noticed the `ordervalue` field has HTML appended to the end of it - which is why the `CAST` and `CONVERT` won't work.

For example, 4.99 is actually `4.99<br />`, and the `<br />` was not visible in the UI

Comment: That is odd it wouldnt appear in UI. It technically should, but what can I say other then "Marketing Cloud" (like the aliens guy meme)

Comment: There's also a dollar sign in the data, which does show up and I totally missed... however, it's still not working - I posted a new question to clear it up.

THANK YOU for the help so far